# datables, Unexpected token ILLEGA

Tags: javascript, apache, datatables

I have a problem with datatables. The code below works when wrapped in script tags within an html document.  If the code is loaded from an external file the browser complains of an "Unexpected token"

```
var oTable = $('#tbFilmes').dataTable({
    'bProcessing': true,
    'sAjaxSource': 'filme/ajaxBuscarFilme',
    'sServerMethod': 'POST',
    'aoColumns': [
        { "sTitle": "Id"},
        { "sTitle": "Name"},
        { "sTitle": "Year"}
    ]
});
```

Inspecting the js file returned by the server shows non ascii characters appended to the file, as shown below.

[image: js Source Code]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxjbepd3kdde7zg/erroJs.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in apache.

I uncommented one line in httpd.conf and it solved the problem.  I found the answer [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/apache-223-corrupt-file-download-issue.html)

> You need to disable following two options:
>
> - **EnableMMAP** - This directive controls whether the httpd may use memory-mapping if it needs to read the contents of a file during delivery. By default, when the handling of a request requires access to the data within a file -- for example, when delivering a server-parsed file using mod_include -- Apache memory-maps the file if the OS supports it.
> - **EnableSendfile** - This directive controls whether httpd may use the sendfile support from the kernel to transmit file contents to the client. By default, when the handling of a request requires no access to the data within a file -- for example, when delivering a static file -- Apache uses sendfile to deliver the file contents without ever reading the file if the OS supports it.
>
> However, these two directives are known to have problem with a network-mounted DocumentRoot (e.g., NFS or SMB), the kernel may be unable to serve the network file through its own cache. So just open httpd.conf on all boxes and changes the following:
>
> ```
> EnableMMAP off
> EnableSendfile off
> ```
>
> Just restart the web server and voila!
>
> ```
> # service httpd restart
> ```

Comment: If the question is answered please mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma after that option.

Use an editor with syntax checking and it will find this kind of problem for you.

Comment: Sorry I dont put here the comma but in my code have. I will post in a code editor. Thanks at moment

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma at the end of `'sServerMethod': 'POST'`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. you are missing a comma at the end of the sServerMethod': 'POST'